# Adding animations to DataTemplate-Generated controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I have some problem with adding animations to DataTemplate-Generated controls. I want to animate Border height.

XAML code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Height="42">
                    <!--There some controls-->
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

There C# code(but it works for only last one item):

```
StoryBoard maxhasb = new Storyboard();
StoryBoard minhasb = new Storyboard();
var maximizeHeightAnimation= new DoubleAnimation(42, 72, duration, FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
var minimizeHeightAnimation= new DoubleAnimation(72, 42, duration, FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
....
ItemsControl itemsControl = (ItemsControl)stackpanel.Children[0];
    foreach (var item in itemsControl.Items)
    {
        ContentPresenter contentPresenter = (ContentPresenter)itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        Border border = (Border)itemsControl.ContentTemplate.LoadContent();
        Storyboard.SetTarget(maximizeHeightAnimation, border);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(maximizeHeightAnimation, new PropertyPath(HeightProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(minimizeHeightAnimation, border);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(minimizeHeightAnimation, new PropertyPath(HeightProperty));
        maxhasb.Children.Add(maximizeHeightAnimation);
        minhasb.Children.Add(minimizeHeightAnimation);
    }
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: With the code above,can you get the controls generated in DataTemplate ?

Comment: *"it works for only ... one item"* - when exactly is the Storyboard supposed to run? You should probably better declare it in XAML, e.g. in the Triggers section of an ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: @zackraiyan, yeah, I have read about this in [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-find-datatemplate-generated-elements).

Comment: @Otabek , maybe u wanted to mentoin CLEMENS in your comment ?

Comment: @Clemens, and what kind of trigger would you recommend?

Comment: No idea, you haven't told us when exactly the Storyboard is supposed to run and what exactly it is supposed to do.

Answer (score -1):

It's quite difficult to work out what you intend doing with this. I guess the idea is to increase the height of an item and then decrease it a bit as it's inserted.
Maybe that isn't exactly what you intend.
You might find the sample for the "Toast" in this article interesting:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31416.wpf-mvvm-friendly-user-notification.aspx#Toast

You probably just want to use a layouttransform to animate ScaleY up and then down without any bounce. But maybe bounce will give you the effect you want or you're not bothered about the specific effect.

From ToastList:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="LightGray">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1.2" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY" From="0" Duration="0:0:.2" FillBehavior="Stop">
                                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        <BounceEase Bounces="2" Bounciness="6"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsGoing}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1.2" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY" To="0" Duration="0:0:1.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Yellow"
                    CornerRadius="3"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Margin="4" Padding="4">
                <Border.BitmapEffect>
                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect ShadowDepth="4" Color="Purple" />
                </Border.BitmapEffect>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Msg}" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextWrapping="Wrap"  MaxWidth="200"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```